# Check if a function was called as a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

In the following minimal example `decorate` is called two times. First using `@decorate`, second by normal function call `decorate(bar)`.

```
def decorate(func):
    print(func.__name__)
    return func

@decorate
def bar():
    pass

decorate(bar)
```

Is it possible to see inside of `decorate` if the call was invoked by using `@decorate` or as a normal function call?

Comment: No because these cases are *exactly the same* The `@` form is just syntactic sugar for the long form

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Please refrain from answering questions in the comments.  Answers in comments are detrimental to the site. Comments cannot be downvoted, only upvoted, and so you can't have the quality checks that answers have. You cannot edit comments to improve them after 5 minutes.

Comment: @wim please let people comment as they wish... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/what-if-i-dont-want-to-answer-but-still-want-to-help

Comment: @wim that's not really an answer. And it seems wrong seeing the good real answers below.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  It starts out "No", and is intended as an answer to the question "Is it possible...?". It's also an incorrect answer. What are you missing here?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, when they are semantically the same? Unless this is purely out of curiosity about the internals of Python, then this is definitely an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What problem are you actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: @kaya3 I don't remember any more. My question is from 2018. Probably I solved the actual problem differently back then. ;-) But I guess it was related to something I tried doing in that library: https://github.com/Dobiasd/undictify

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `@decorator` syntax is just syntactic sugar, thus both examples have identical behaviour. This also means whatever distinction you are doing between them might not be as meaningful as you thought.

Although, you can use `inspect` to read your script and see how the decorator was called in the above frame.

```
import inspect

def decorate(func):
    # See explanation below
    lines = inspect.stack(context=2)[1].code_context
    decorated = any(line.startswith('@') for line in lines)

    print(func.__name__, 'was decorated with "@decorate":', decorated)
    return func
```

Note that we had to specify `context=2` to the `inspect.stack` function. The `context` argument indicates how many lines of code around the current line must be returned. In some specific cases, such as when decorating a subclass, the current line was on the class declaration instead of the decorator. [The exact reason for this behaviour has been explored here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193338/5079316)

### Example

```
@decorate
def bar():
    pass

def foo():
    pass
foo = decorate(foo)

@decorate
class MyDict(dict):
    pass
```

### Output

```
bar was decorated with "@decorate": True
foo was decorated with "@decorate": False
MyDict was decorated with "@decorate": True
```

### Caveat

There are still some corner cases that we can hardly overcome such as linebreaks between the decorator and a class declaration.

```
# This will fail
@decorate

class MyDict(dict):
    pass
```

Comment: did you try to call `bar` once more time?

Comment: @BearBrown `bar` is never called in the given code.

Comment: Nice Idea! However it does not work in all cases, like in [this one](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/352f9b4f188a941b1728f402d4bb0e53).

Comment: @TobiasHermann That is an extemely specific example, I have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: It seems the behaviour of inspect is different when decorating a class that inherits

Comment: congratulations for this answer. Good python questions (& answers) are so rare ATM...

Comment: @TobiasHermann Although, I don't get why the behaviour is different, so I [asked the question myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192877/why-does-inspect-returns-different-line-for-class-inheriting-from-superclass).

Comment: Thanks a lot! However it breaks with a function like [this](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/345818cba0821cb47c351a938b31d37e).

Comment: @TobiasHermann Since it is somewhat of a hack, it will break on many cornercases. You could improve the solution to dynamicaly grab the desired context size and find the decorator line. But that is very expensive and maybe not worth it

Comment: OK, I think I will just try to circumvent the problem. But thanks for interesting investigation nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 4):

Olivier's answer took the thoughts right out of my head. However, as `inspect.stack()` is a particularly expensive call, I would consider opting to use something along the lines of:

```
frame = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe().f_back, context=1)
if frame.code_context[0][0].startswith('@'): 
    print('Used as @decorate: True')
else:
    print("Used as @decorate: False")
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the inspect api could do that

Comment: Although in Python 3.6.2 on Windows 10, I get `'frame' object has no attribute 'code_context'`

Comment: The trick with that: the decorator is called only once at import time. Within a function call it is not involved anymore.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thank you for pointing that out, I have adjusted the example to work for python >=3.5

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to popular believe, `@decorator` and `decorator(…)` are not exactly equivalent. The first runs *before* name binding, the latter *after* name binding. For the common use-case of top-level functions, this allows to cheaply test which case applies.

```
import sys

def decoraware(subject):
    """
    Decorator that is aware whether it was applied using `@deco` syntax
    """
    try:
        module_name, qualname = subject.__module__, subject.__qualname__
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError(f"subject must define '__module__' and '__qualname__' to find it")
    if '.' in qualname:
        raise ValueError(f"subject must be a top-level function/class")
    # see whether ``subject`` has been bound to its module
    module = sys.modules[module_name]
    if getattr(module, qualname, None) is not subject:
        print('@decorating', qualname)  # @decoraware
    else:
        print('wrapping()', qualname)   # decoraware()
    return subject
```

This example will merely print how it was applied.

```
>>> @decoraware
... def foo(): ...
...
@decorating foo
>>> decoraware(foo)
wrapping() foo
```

The same means can be used to run arbitrary code in each path, though.

In case that multiple decorators are applied, you must decide whether you want the top or bottom subject. For the top-function, the code works unmodified. For the bottom subject, unwrap it using [`subject = inspect.unwrap(subject)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.unwrap) before detection.

---

The same approach can be used in a more general way on CPython. Using `sys._getframe(n).f_locals` gives access to the local namespace in which the decorator was applied.

```
def decoraware(subject):
    """Decorator that is aware whether it was applied using `@deco` syntax"""
    modname, topname = subject.__module__, subject.__name__
    if getattr(sys.modules[modname], topname, None) is subject:
        print('wrapping()', topname, '[top-level]')
    else:
        at_frame = sys._getframe(1)
        if at_frame.f_locals.get(topname) is subject:
            print('wrapping()', topname, '[locals]')
        elif at_frame.f_globals.get(topname) is subject:
            print('wrapping()', topname, '[globals]')
        else:
            print('@decorating', topname)
    return subject
```

---

Note that similar to `pickle`, this approach will fail if the subject's `__qualname__`/`__name__` is tampered with or it is `del`'ed from its defining namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the two previous answers, I wrote a generic function which should work as expected in almost all real-world cases. I tested it with Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8.

Before copy-pasting this function into your code, make sure you wouldn't be better off using the [`decorator` module](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/) instead.

```py
def am_I_called_as_a_decorator(default=False):
    """This function tries to determine how its caller was called.

    The value returned by this function should not be blindly trusted, it can
    sometimes be inaccurate.

    Arguments:
        default (bool): the fallback value to return when we're unable to determine
                        how the function was called

    >>> def f(*args):
    ...     if am_I_called_as_a_decorator():
    ...         print("called as decorator with args {!r}".format(args))
    ...         if len(args) == 1:
    ...             return args[0]
    ...         return f
    ...     else:
    ...         print("called normally with args {!r}".format(args))
    ...
    >>> f()
    called normally with args ()
    >>> @f                              #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    ... def g(): pass
    ...
    called as decorator with args (<function g at ...>,)
    >>> @f()
    ... class Foobar: pass
    ...
    called as decorator with args ()
    called as decorator with args (<class 'state_chain.Foobar'>,)
    >>> @f(                             #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    ...     'one long argument',
    ...     'another long argument',
    ... )
    ... def g(): pass
    ...
    called as decorator with args ('one long argument', 'another long argument')
    called as decorator with args (<function g at ...>,)
    >>> @f('one long argument',         #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    ...    'another long argument')
    ... def g(): pass
    ...
    called as decorator with args ('one long argument', 'another long argument')
    called as decorator with args (<function g at ...>,)
    >>> @f(                             #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    ...     # A weirdly placed comment
    ...   )
    ... @f
    ... def g(): pass
    ...
    called as decorator with args ()
    called as decorator with args (<function g at ...>,)

    """

    def get_indentation(line):
        for i, c in enumerate(line):
            if not c.isspace():
                break
        return line[:i]

    # First, we try to look at the line where Python says the function call is.
    # Unfortunately, Python doesn't always give us the line we're interested in.
    call_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    call_info = inspect.getframeinfo(call_frame, context=0)
    source_lines = linecache.getlines(call_info.filename)
    if not source_lines:
        # Reading the source code failed, return the fallback value.
        return default
    try:
        call_line = source_lines[call_info.lineno - 1]
    except IndexError:
        # The source file seems to have been modified.
        return default
    call_line_ls = call_line.lstrip()
    if call_line_ls.startswith('@'):
        # Note: there is a small probability of false positive here, if the
        # function call is on the same line as a decorator call.
        return True
    if call_line_ls.startswith('class ') or call_line_ls.startswith('def '):
        # Note: there is a small probability of false positive here, if the
        # function call is on the same line as a `class` or `def` keyword.
        return True
    # Next, we try to find and examine the line after the function call.
    # If that line doesn't start with a `class` or `def` keyword, then the
    # function isn't being called as a decorator.
    def_lineno = call_info.lineno
    while True:
        try:
            def_line = source_lines[def_lineno]
        except IndexError:
            # We've reached the end of the file.
            return False
        def_line_ls = def_line.lstrip()
        if def_line_ls[:1] in (')', '#', '@', ''):
            def_lineno += 1
            continue
        break
    if not (def_line_ls.startswith('class') or def_line_ls.startswith('def')):
        # Note: there is a small probability of false negative here, as we might
        # be looking at the wrong line.
        return False
    # Finally, we look at the lines above, taking advantage of the fact that a
    # decorator call is at the same level of indentation as the function or
    # class being decorated.
    def_line_indentation = get_indentation(def_line)
    for lineno in range(call_info.lineno - 1, 0, -1):
        line = source_lines[lineno - 1]
        line_indentation = get_indentation(line)
        if line_indentation == def_line_indentation:
            line_ls = line.lstrip()
            if line_ls[:1] in (')', ','):
                continue
            return line_ls.startswith('@')
        elif len(line_indentation) < len(def_line_indentation):
            break
    return default
```