# Why does inspect return different line for class inheriting from superclass?

Tags: python, python-3.6, decorator, python-decorators, inspect

While trying to figure out if [a function is called with the `@decorator` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52192154/5079316), we realized that `inspect` has a different behaviour when looking at a decorated class that inherits from a superclass.

The following behaviour was found with CPython 3.6.2 under Windows 10.

It was also reproduced in CPython 3.7.0 under Linux 64 bits.

```
import inspect

def decorate(f):
    lines = inspect.stack()[1].code_context
    print(f.__name__, lines)

    return f

@decorate
class Foo:
    pass

@decorate
class Bar(dict):
    pass
```

### Output

```
Foo ['@decorate\n']
Bar ['class Bar(dict):\n']
```

Why does inheritance change the behaviour of `inspect`?

Comment: Can't reproduce that behavior on Python 3.6. Are you sure you're not using Python 2.x?

Comment: I doubt it's relevant here, but just in case, it would probably be better to make `Bar` inherit from a Python type rather than a builtin (and make the decorator `return f`, so you can use `Foo` as that class to inherit).

Comment: *Can* reproduce on Python 3.6 here, which kind of surprises me, given the results of some other experiments.

Comment: @kindall Python 3.6 under Windows 10

Comment: @abarnert It is unrelated indeed. Although, I'll update for everyone's peace of mind

Comment: I can repro on 3.6 in the interactive interpreter, both stock and IPython, on Mac, Linux, and repl.it. But when I put the same code in a script, the code_context is `None` for both functions on Linux and repl.it.

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure `code_context` is just generated from `filename` and `lineno` via `linecache`, so the question is: is the `lineno` different by one, or is `linecache` acting weird?

Comment: I can repro in a script, and I wouldn't expect this to work interactively unless you're on something like IPython, since interactive mode shouldn't save the source code.

Comment: It's `lineno` differing by 1, [as you can see on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MajorArtisticCharacterencoding), which narrows down what to look at.

Comment: Simpler test: the frame objects have different `f_lineno` values, [again at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MajorArtisticCharacterencoding). So it's nothing to do with `inspect`, it's how CPython tracks line numbers in frame objects…

Comment: Also, [an empty base list is the same as not having a base list, but `object` is the same as having one](https://repl.it/repls/MajorArtisticCharacterencoding).

Comment: Disassembly with `dis` shows that the line number is advanced for the LOAD_NAME that loads the base class object, which doesn't happen with no base class.

Comment: @abarnert You've posted the same link 3 times now :D

Comment: @Aran-Fey Oops; it I guess I disabled versioning…

Comment: @user2357112 I see the same, I think you got it.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, that's it. You could test further—what if you do a `LOAD_FAST` or `LOAD_CONST` for the base—if you really want to.

Comment: (What confuses me now is why pdb pointed to `@dec` for both cases when I put a `pdb.set_trace()` in the decorator.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Further experiment shows that this is a quirk of Python's line number assignment. Particularly, if we use `dis` to see the disassembly of [code with and without a base class](https://ideone.com/bmt4hz):

```
import dis
import sys

dis.dis(sys._getframe().f_code)

def dec(): pass

@dec
class Foo: pass

@dec
class Bar(Foo): pass
```

We see that for `Foo`, the instructions involved have line number 8 (corresponding to the `@dec` line):

```
  8          58 LOAD_NAME                4 (dec)
             61 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
             62 LOAD_CONST               4 (<code object Foo at 0x2b2a65422810, file "./prog.py", line 8>)
             65 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Foo')
             68 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             71 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Foo')
             74 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             77 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             80 STORE_NAME               5 (Foo)
```

But for `Bar`, the line number advances from 11 to 12 for the `LOAD_NAME` that loads the base class:

```
 11          83 LOAD_NAME                4 (dec)
             86 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
             87 LOAD_CONST               6 (<code object Bar at 0x2b2a654a0f60, file "./prog.py", line 11>)
             90 LOAD_CONST               7 ('Bar')
             93 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             96 LOAD_CONST               7 ('Bar')

 12          99 LOAD_NAME                5 (Foo)
            102 CALL_FUNCTION            3 (3 positional, 0 keyword pair)
            105 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
            108 STORE_NAME               6 (Bar)
```

With no base class, the parent frame's `f_lineno` is on the `@` line when the decorator runs. With a base class, the parent frame is on the load-the-base-class line.